# Calling a Stoc Proc from MVC in c# - Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, call

I am trying to call a stor proc from my MVC c# project this code is in the model

```
    public IQueryable<Make> GetMake()
    {
        var FillMake = db.GetMake2();
        return FillMake;
    }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult'
>   to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

The Stor Proc is showing in the datacontext view and the contents is:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER Proc [dbo].[GetMake2]
AS
select *  from dbo.Make;
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: change your return type to `IEnumerable<Make>`

Answer (score 0):

Even though the stored procedure returns records from the `Make` table, the result of the call in the generated LINQ to SQL code isn't of type `IQueryable<Make>`, so you need to convert it before returning the result from the method.  This happens because the LINQ to SQL generating code doesn't quite "know" the shape of the result set from the stored procedure.

[Here's a good tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: Sorry how would I go about converting it, do I need to cast the stor proc call? I looked at the tutorial and it seems to be doing the same as me  - but I guess Mr Gu's example works.

Comment: @Kitemark76: Taking another look at the code and the error, I'm not entirely sure.  It's getting an `ISingleResult` from the stored procedure?  Something doesn't seem quite right.  It seems like it's expecting only one record to come back from the stored procedure.  Has the LINQ data context been re-generated since the stored procedure was altered?  I'd go with @Eranga's suggestion to make the return type `IEnumerable<Make>` and see where that gets you.